# Blazor Web Assembly PWA - Install Dialog

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

Is there a way in Blazor Web Assembly PWA to add an "Install" dialog prompt? Something similar to Youtube Music

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 5):

The rough flow is

- Register for `beforeinstallprompt`
- When that event fires, store the event for later (sounds odd but you need it)
- Call into Blazor to display a prompt alert
- Call back to JS and use the stashed event to start the install process

### Register for install prompt notification

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    // where you store it is up to you
    window.PWADeferredPrompt = e;
    // Notify C# Code that it can show an alert 
    // MyBlazorInstallMethod must be [JSInvokable]
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync("MyBlazorAssembly", "MyBlazorInstallMethod");
});
```

This C# method can then display an alert to say the user can install as a desktop app and offer Install/Cancel buttons.

#### Register a JS function you can call from Blazor/C#

```js
window.BlazorPWA = {
    installPWA: function () {
        if (window.PWADeferredPrompt) {
            // Use the stashed event to continue the install process
            window.PWADeferredPrompt.prompt();
            window.PWADeferredPrompt.userChoice
                .then(function (choiceResult) {
                    window.PWADeferredPrompt = null;
                });
        }
    }
};
```

#### Blazor code

```cs
[JSInvokable]
public async Task MyBlazorInstallMethod()
{
  // show an alert and get the result
  ...
  // tell browser to install
  if (UserChoseInstall)
  {
    await jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorPWA.installPWA");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you perhaps share a simple solution for this? I tried putting your code in but my interop fails saying it can't find installPWA

Comment: @Quinton It would be better for you to ask a new question with your specific problem

Comment: can't find installPWA? try "YourAppNameInManifest.installPWA" instead of "BlazorPWA.installPWA"

Comment: Add what point did you register the "beforeinstallprompt" event? When I register it simply in the js file that I´m including, the .Net method is not called because the .Net dispatcher has not been set yet. If I register manually (OnAfterRender) the event is not fired. The only thing that worked for me so far is to just check if the deferred prompt has been set manually but I´m unsure if the scope or lifetime of the js variable is a problem?